# Is this an FxCop bug for a VB.NET implementation referencing a C# interface containing generics?

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, nullable, fxcop

We have an application in VB.NET that is referencing a C# library. An interface definition is in the C# library and the implementation is in the VB.NET application. One of the interface definitions is a typed method for a nullable struct.

FxCop can't analyse correctly and reports an error of:

> The following error was encountered while reading module 'Console': Could not resolve member reference: [Library, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]Library.IWithGeneric::GetSomething.

I have created a basic outline application to prove this.

Is the code missing something so that FxCop can load the module (it compiles and runs with no warnings)?
Or is it simply an FxCop bug?

**IWithGeneric.cs**

```
namespace Library
{
    public interface IWithGeneric
    {
        T? GetSomething<T>() where T : struct;
    }
}
```

**VbGenericImplementation.vb**

```
Imports Library

Public Class VbGenericImplementation
    Implements IWithGeneric

    Public Function GetSomething(Of T As Structure)() As T? Implements IWithGeneric.GetSomething
        Return New T
    End Function

End Class
```

**Root.vb**

```
Module Root

    Sub Main()

        Dim test As New VbGenericImplementation

        Dim result = test.GetSomething(Of Integer)()

        System.Console.WriteLine(result)
        System.Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: As you say, the code compiles and runs correctly, so there is nothing wrong with the code. FxCop on the other hand seems to have a problem, either because it can't find the DLL (is it there?), or because it has a bug. What version of FxCop are you using?

Comment: Agreed, but it might be compiling and running but not done in the best practice way. FxCop Version 10 (10.0.30319.1)

Comment: If that were true, you would think that FxCop would have a better way of letting you know than blowing up.

Comment: I have raised this with [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/870827/fxcop-10-0-unable-to-process-vb-net-assembly-containing-c-generics-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have closed the issue as a bug that will be "resolved naturally":

> It's odd that the IL here is confusing FxCop so badly! For VS "14" we're moving from IL-based analysis to a source-based analysis engine built on Roslyn. As we make that transition, this sort of issue should be resolved naturally.
>
> Alex Turner
>
> Senior Program Manager
>
> Visual Basic and C# Compiler

From: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/870827/fxcop-10-0-unable-to-process-vb-net-assembly-containing-c-generics-implementation